# OllyDbg: How to set conditional breakpoint on a register value?

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg, strings, breakpoint

I want to set a breakpoint when the register EAX references a specific Unicode string, e.g. "Enter". In Ollydbg there is usually right beside the EAX value a string that says "ASCII: Enter ".

I read that I have to use Olly v1.10 for this purpose. When I go to "Debug" -> "Set Condition" I can write in the text field "Condition is TRUE" for instance this:

```
EAX == 00000010
```

I press F9 (Run) and the breakpoint will work. So once EAX becomes 0x10 olly will stop. However when I do this:

```
UNICODE[EAX] == "Enter"
```

it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Doesn't matter which program I use and which Olly version, I can't get this to work. I would like to match strings like "Enter text" as well, so any appearance of "Enter".

In the end I'm basically looking for a way to stop olly once a specific string is loaded into RAM. How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a slight syntax change between 1.1 and 2.01 the square are compulsory even when not dereferencing

so to have a condition where eax points to unicode string you need a condition like

**[UNICODE EAX] == "what"**

suppose you have code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
wchar_t *strings[] = { L"is this what", L"does it matter", L"what is this",
  L"who are you", L"why am i doing this", L"lest scoot from here"
};
PWCHAR foo (int a) {
  return strings[a];
}
int main(void ) {
  for(int i=5;i>=0;i--) {
    printf("%S\n",foo(i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

setting a break as shown in screenshot will break correctly in 2.01
[image]

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint in Olly 2.01? Did you typed `[UNICODE EAX] == "what"` in "Trace" -> "Set Condition" -> "Condition 1 is true" ? Still not working for me.

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't want to set a breakpoint on a specific address (in your example 00DF1295) and check EAX value changes. I want to look for a specific string once it is loaded for the first time in the register EAX (or in any register actually).

Comment: tracing condition is not breakpoint condition that is a seperate question breakpoints are always tied to some instruction pointer  while tracing eax can hold anything from 0 to 2^31 in a 32 bit machine per instruction  you cannot read the memory of eax if eax = 0 or for that matter any unreadable memory address  please post a seperate question

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set a conditional breakpoint in both OllyDbg 1.01 and 2.00
For example in Olly 2, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> you can type your condition **UNICODE [EAX] ==  "Enter"** in the dialog box.
If the debugger doesn't break on the condition you can check the values of *EAX* by setting a conditional log breakpoint(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>). set the settings like shown:
[image]

Now while the program is running and you are waiting to break here, open the log window and check what are the values in *EAX* and why the debugger is not breaking.

Comment: When I press SHIFT+F2 I can only set a breakpoint on a specific address. But I don't want to do that. I want Olly to stop once a specific ASCII, e.g. "what", is loaded into the register EAX (it can be any place/address in the program). So Olly needs to run over the whole program and not just one address like 001A74EF in your example.

Comment: If your specific string is hardcoded in the program you can find it in dump and set a breakpoint on it. Otherwise you should break on all the commands that load something in EAX either using MOV or LEA or...