# x64dbg: break when a register contains a value

Tags: x64dbg, breakpoint, register

Is there a way to break code execution when a register contains a particular value with x64dbg? I'm not talking about setting a conditional breakpoint at a specific location, but about watching the registers permanently and breaking as soon as the value is found. Ideally, I'd like to check the registers for string references, if possible.

If such functionality doesn't exist, I'd be willing to try and implement it myself, if you could point me in the right direction, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the similar [question for OllyDbg](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/), it seems you should be able to achieve it by using [*Conditional Tracing*](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/ConditionalTracing.html).

The doc also mentions:

> You can start a conditional tracing by “Trace over until
>   condition”/”Trace into until condition” commands in the Debug menu.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about that myself and tried to use it. However, when I start the trace, the debuggee becomes unresponsive until the trace is over. I need to interact with the ui while the trace is running, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Tracing is very slow as it needs to stop at every instruction to check the condition. Try to limit it to the smallest piece of code  you can.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get anywhere with that, thank you. I suppose there isn't any other way then? Could something like that "easily" be added to x64dbg or would it be similarly slow to tracing?